# Azure pipeline unable to connect to Azure Sql

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to use the copy data function in ADF to copy data from an in house server to an Azure database. Now when I test the two connections they complete and I am able to pull data. It's almost like it's trying to use the on-premises runtime for the Azure connection. I have opened the firewall to Azure services but still unable to get it to validate.

And on top of this if I write it to a azure blob then copy it that data set it works

However as soon as I try validate the copy it gives me the following error:

> Fail to connect to AzureDWCORP from Integration Runtime: onPremDBEngine.
> Error message: Cannot connect to SQL Database: 'xxxxxx.database.windows.net',
> Database: 'XXX_DEV', User: 'xxxxx'.
>
> Check the linked service configuration is correct, and make sure the SQL Database firewall allows the integration runtime to access. A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.), SqlErrorNumber=10060,Class=20,State=0, A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond .

Comment: Where is the in house SQL Server? If It's in the VM, you need self-host integration runtime to connect it.

Comment: @LeonYue It is connected and I can run lookups on it and get data back. Connection is not the issue its something to do with the copy data function

Answer (score 0):

So if anyone ever has this same error what I did to get around it was to load the data into a Azure table storage then pull it out of that into the destination table. This will allow you to switch between integrated run times.